# Cherokee/WordPress links to media files are WRONG

Tags: rewrite, wordpress, cherokee

I have a problem with WordPress links to media files.

It is currently pointing to (which is wrong/won't work/nothing loads):
http://mydomain.com/files/2012/10/image_4-1.png

The correct URL is to retrieve the image is (works/image is loaded into browser):
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/2012/10/image_4-1.png

So, how do I get Cherokee to redirect everything from:
http://mydomain.com/files/
to:
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/

... and note that the "mydomain.com" corresponds to the "5" in the correct URL path.

--

I need either of these solutions:

How do I configure Cherokee Web Server to correctly redirect (rewrite) to the correct URL? (In  Cherokee, I'm using Virtual Server, so I can statically map the domain name to the "5" in the correct URL.)

OR,

How do I set the settings within WordPress to correct this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I have resolved this problem by rewriting "^/files/(.*)" to "http://mydomain.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/$1" (Cherokee redirection).